# Check the identity $A\cap (B - C)=(A\cap B) - (A\cap C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$A\cap (B - C)=(A\cap B) - (A\cap C)$$

I am trying to prove this by set algebra from left to right. I can do it from right to left and also using mutual inclusions, but get stuck in $\rightarrow$.
This is what I got till now.

$A\cap(B-C)=A\cap(B\cap C^c)$    By definition

$= (A\cap B)\cap C^c$  by associativity

$=(A\cap B)-C$   by definition

Don't know how to get it....

Answer (score 2):

$(A\cap B)-C = (A\cap B)-(A \cap C)$ because subtracting elements from $(A\cap B) \subset A$ which are not in $A$ won't do anything, they aren't in there anyway.

Comment: You mean $A^c $ ?

Comment: You might want to clarify that? I said not in A, so in $A^c$, if you meant that?

Comment: Ok, got it now, ty